# a missing font causes RAM overflow, huge syslog file, then crash ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, fonts, pdf, evince, texlive

I have some PDFs open in Document Viewer (3.28.4), academic papers downloaded from arXiv recently. Then I notice my memory usage rising gradually, eventually overwhelmed all the available RAM, which I have 40Gb. This froze the box and I have to do a hard reboot.

When I look at /var/log/syslog, I found it is enormous, ~50Gb. In it, these two lines keep repeating,

```
Nov 17 15:30:35 homantin nemo.desktop[3193]: page: Warning: font `cmr10' not found, trying metric files instead
Nov 17 15:30:35 homantin nemo.desktop[3193]: page: Error: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm: File corrupted, or not a TFM file
```

While this is happening, I captured htop and it shows evince-thumbnailer is running at 100% CPU.

I found this bug [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1497727) on evince-thumbnailer, but there is no fix.

This happened when I was not using LaTeX (texlive) at all.

Ubuntu 18.04
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3

**UPDATE (Nov 24, 2019)**:

I just noticed this happened without having any PDF opened in any application. While I was doing something (browsing files in Files), evince-thumbnailer pops up in htop, running and taking up 100% of a core. No PDF is opened anywhere. All browsers were closed.

Comment: Can you share the PDF so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: One more thing, what if you open it with another PDF reader, like Foxit Reader? What happens?

Comment: @MostafaNajafiyazdi I do not know which particular one caused the problem. I had ~15 files open at the time.

Comment: I just hit exactly this problem. It seems to be a problem with `cmr10.tfm` - that's the font that I had trouble with, and also someone else had this issue here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195966/texlive-problems-in-log-file - I've seen it with .pdfs and the thumbnailer (I think for .svgs with use the font). I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. See also https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2277168

Comment: I just got a `cmr10.tfm` from somewhere online (datestamped from 1995) and diffed it with the one on my system - they're identical. It seems unlikely that a font has been broken for 25 years without anyone noticing, so my guess is that it's a Ubuntu/Gnome problem.

Comment: @horaceT Are you still having this problem? PDFs do not use `tfm` files. They are specific to TeX/LaTeX. Based on the bug report, it appears to occur when the thumbnailer tries to generate thumbnails of `dvi` files. Consider switching to `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or some other variant that generates `pdf` files directly.

Comment: @xiota Problem seems to be gone.  I'm still using Doc Viewer though. So something must hv been fixed.

Comment: @horaceT Based on what I can find elsewhere, it's associated with TeX/LaTeX `dvi` files.

Comment: The problem still exists in Debian 11 (Evince 3.38.2-1)