# texlive problems in log file

Tags: disk-usage, log, latex

I am having problems with my log file in ubuntu. The log files are becoming so big ~8gb that it's slowing my machine down.

The log complains of the following:

> Warning: font `cmr10' not found, trying metric files instead
>
> page: Error: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm: File corrupted, or not a TFM file

I was able to find a `cmr10.tfm` file online and replaced it with the one I had. Yet, the problem still persists.

Can anyone guide me to solve this problem? I am thinking of reinstalling texlive. Help appreciated.

Comment: How did you install TeXlive, from standard repositories, ppa, compiled your own, some other way? Which version of TeXlive is it? Also indicate which version/flavor of Ubuntu you are using. Please update your question with the new information.

Comment: I just ran into exactly this problem, with exactly this font file, so local file corruption seems unlikely. Ubuntu 16.04, texlive packages from the standard repos.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189647/a-missing-font-causes-ram-overflow-huge-syslog-file-then-crash-ubuntu and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2277168

Comment: @carthurs The only programs that use `tfm` files are associated with TeX. Do have any `dvi` files on your computer? Consider getting rid of them and switching to `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, or other variants that generate `pdf` files directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed TexLive from Ubuntu repository - then you need to reinstall package which provides this [*cmr10.tfm* file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=cmr10.tfm) with single command below:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-base
```

and then the problem will be solved.

If the problem persists - you can detect problematic packages with `debsums` or reinstall all with brute-force method:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -i texlive | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: This gives 'Reinstallation of texlive-base is not possible, it cannot be downloaded' for me -- the package seems to not be available on newer Ubuntu versions?